# Can I use a member variable as a key to a hash_set/hash_map?

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap

I have a class like this:

```
class Foo
{
   long long Id;
   string x;
   string y;
   // other member variables and functions
};
```

I would like to store this in a `hash_set` (or `hash_map`), but use the Id member variable as the key for inserting and searching. I'm not sure how I can do this. I thought of the following ways, but none of them are really good:

1) I can write a custom hash function that will hash the object using the Id, but then I can't use the `find()` method on `hash_set` to lookup the item by Id (`long long`) since it will require a `Foo` object to be passed-in.

2) I can duplicate the Id and create a`hash_map<long long, Foo>` instead of a `hash_set<long long, Foo>` but I have 100 million instances of these objects so I'd rather not duplicate the Id field.

3) I can move the Id field outside of `Foo` and then do `hash_map<long long, Foo>`, but it would be kind of messy since the Id is used internally by the class and it would be better to keep it with `Foo`.

Any ideas? What I'm looking for is a way to store `Foo` objects but be able to search for them in the `hash_set` using a `long long` (by Id).

Thanks!

Comment: What's the usage pattern for this? Are you setting this up once and then only read from it or do you keep modifying the set?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a particularly elegant solution, but it works: define an `operator <` (and `operator ==` as well, as CashCow suggested) for your class that orders objects based on the `Id` field, then when you want to do a `find`, pass in a dummy object that contains the `Id` you're looking for.

Comment: Works great for a standard set or map, not so great for hash-based containers. The `operator <`, I mean.

Comment: Why not? I thought hash-based containers still depend on `operator <` to ultimately ensure that two objects are equal.

Comment: Both `hash_map` and `unordered_map` appear to take a comparison functor for equality, not less than.

Comment: It seems `unordered_map` uses `equal_to<Key>` for comparison, but at least VC++'s `hash_map` uses `hash_compare<Key, less<Key>>`.

Comment: Just overload the equality operator too. And for the hashing function itself just return the id.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) I can write a custom hash function
>   that will hash the object using the
>   Id, but then I can't use the find()
>   method on hash_set to lookup the item
>   by Id (long long) since it will
>   require a Foo object to be passed-in.

This is a common problem with the standard map and set containers. Add a constructor or static member that creates a comparison object, an object with only the key member valid.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is your best bet among the three you gave. If you're up to it, you could write a custom hash_set (even just a wrapper around the regular one) to provide what you want. In that case, I'd prefer option 1. You could easily add a find function that takes just the key value and adapts it to use the internal find function properly giving you all benefits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with it, but boost::multiindex is built on top of boost::hash by default, and has explicit support for looking up an object in a hash using only a key found in the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find an actual solution for the hash_set/hash_map containers, you may want to consider using the [uthash](http://uthash.sourceforge.net/) hash table implementation, which supports your use case directly. It's C though and it's based on macros but it's one of the most popular hash table implementations that exist.